# Stat showing label value in Grafana 8

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grafana-dashboard

I have Prometheus data like this

```
browser_login_test_duration_seconds{host="https://host-a",status="success"} 7.703323435
browser_login_test_duration_seconds{host="https://host-b",status="failed"} 4.19048497
```

I use the data to graph the average time it takes to login for example, or how often it fails for a host.

I'd like to create another panel that shows the current status for each host.
I'm able to display this in a table no problem.  But I think a Stat panel would be nicer.
The panel should have the name of the host and text for the current status.  Bonus if it shows the time series of original values in the bg but not necessary.